# how to style sqlite selection

Tags: javascript, sqlite, select, styles

I have the following bill table

```
building      flatname   flatdescription   amount      pastpayments     receiptno
1234          name a     a                 123         0                0
1234          name a     a                 12          10               39
1234          name a     a                 125         125              40
1235          name a     a                 133         10               41
1235          name b     b                 125         125              50
1234          name c     c                 100         90               0
```

I want to select rows that amount minus payments is greater than zero with buildingcode 1234 and display them with style b if there is receiptno > 0 within the same name and no style if there is no receiptno > 0 within the same name

so the result from my code must be as follow

```
         name a     39    with style B
         name c     0
```

How can I do this?

I use the following code but I receive all the selections with no style

```
            t.executeSql('SELECT receiptno AS mr, flatdescription, flatname, buildingcode FROM bill WHERE amount - pastpayments> 0 AND buildingcode = ? GROUP BY buildingcode, flatname ORDER BY flatdescription DESC',[buildingcode], function(t, resultflat) {


            var i,
                len = resultflat.rows.length,
                row;

            if (len > 0 ) {
                items.push('<br>');
                for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
                    row = resultflat.rows.item(i);

                    if (row.mr > 0) {

                        items.push('<li data-theme="b" data-icon="false" style="height:40px; padding: 7px 0 0 0; font-size: 1.2em"><a href="#displayflat" data-flat="' + row.flatname + '" data-description="' + row.flatdescription + '">' + row.flatdescription + '...' + row.flatname + '</a></li>');

                        } else {
                        items.push('<li data-icon="false" style="height:40px; padding: 7px 0 0 0; font-size: 1.2em"><a href="#displayflat" data-flat="' + row.flatname + '" data-description="' + row.flatdescription + '">' + row.flatdescription + '...' + row.flatname + '</a></li>');

                        }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple records in the group that has `building=1234` and `flatname='name a'`.
Just saying `receiptno` will give you the value from some *random* one of these records.

You probably want to use `MAX(receiptno)` to get the largest value in the group; this ensures that you get a non-zero `receiptno` if there is one in the group.